# Why are my menu links centered when i wrapped them in <ul> tags?

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-lists

I am currently just creating some random files with exemplary pieces of code (i am aware that i might not have the most optimal way of doing something but i just started out, but please do share if you see anything that i could improve on basic structure), i was creating a  section and forgot to put the `<li>` items in `<ul>` tags but i found out that my links went from left aligned to centered once i did and i have no idea what property is causing that. It's not a problem at all but i just want to know how that works

This is the structure of my nav section with the CSS styling included

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .ML {
                font-size: 20pt;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-right: 0.5cm;
            }

            
            li {
                display: inline;
            }

            /* unvisited link */
            a:link {
                color: red;
            }

            /* visited link */
            a:visited {     
                color: green;
            }

            /* mouse over link */
            a:hover {       
                color: hotpink;
            }

            /* selected link */
            a:active {      
                color: blue;
    }       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="index.html">Home Page</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="Styling.html">Basic CSS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="Links.html">Using Links</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="Videos.html">Using Videos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="Lists.html">Using Lists</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="Tables.html">Using Tables</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="DivsAndSpans.html">Using Divs & Spans</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="InputAndForms.html">Using Inputs and Forms</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ML" href="iFrames.html">Using iFrames</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>` elements by default have padding on the left. The elements aren't truly being centered.

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('ul')).paddingLeft);
```

```css
li{display:inline;}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<li>Item</li>
```